# How can I make an iframe inside of a <td> 33 percent of the screen width?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an I frame inside of a `<td>` element. I'd like to dynamically scale the `iframe` so that it takes up `33%` of the screen `width` (and automatically fixes the `height`).

When I try this:

```
<iframe src="google drive presentation url" frameborder="0" width="33vw" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

It only takes up `33%` of the `<td>` element (which also has text in it).

Also, I tried using `width="33%"` but that didn't work either.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must give `width` using CSS instead.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
td {
  width: 33.3%;
  background: red
}
iframe {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <iframe src="google drive presentation url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
    </td>
    <td>
      Foo Bar
    </td>
    <td>
      Foo Bar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hm, that still isn't working unfortunately. It makes it 33.3% of the <td> element.

Comment: oh you want 100% of the `td` which is already a 33% of the screen?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I just got back otherwise I'd have accepted sooner sorry.

Comment: Glad to help :) you may try with `vw` as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you supporting anything older than IE9? Can you use [`vw` units](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport.html)?

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itopizarro/stnu1p9u/) of the (rough) idea. The `<div>` elements on the bottom are for measurement/comparison.

Comment: I am not supporting anything but chrome (its not for public, just a school project), so yes vw should work. However, when I try vw it seems to be doing the same as %.